# SQL Get Top 10 records by date

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table full of bugs.  The BugTitle is the page erroring and I also capture the error line.
I would like to build an SQL Query that selects the top 10 bugs based on bugtitle and error line.
I have this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(BugTitle) AS BugCount, BugTitle, ErrLine 
FROM Bugs 
WHERE BugDate >= DateAdd(Day, -30, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate())) 
GROUP BY BugTitle, ErrLine 
ORDER BY BugCount, ErrLine DESC
```

But I'm not sure if it's correct.  I'm pretty sure that my test data only has 1 bug that happens on the same line but that's not showing up with this query.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the top 10 most frequent you probably want to order by the count:

```
SELECT TOP(10) COUNT(BugTitle) AS BugCount, BugTitle, ErrLine
FROM Bugs
WHERE BugDate >= DateAdd(Day, -30, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()))
GROUP BY BugTitle, ErrLine
ORDER BY COUNT(BugTitle) DESC
```

Comment: ORDER BY BugCount like he did is not enough?

Comment: *edit*
It appears your query does work as a copy-paste of yours is perfect, I must have mistyped.

Comment: @Pselus: Heh... it's OK. Happens sometimes. :)