# SQL Get Top 10 bug records by count but with ID

Tags: sql, t-sql

I asked a question earlier today [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575574/sql-get-top-10-records-by-date).
However, what I neglected to check with that question is how can I get AN id of those bug records?
So for example, if I have a bug that has happened 3 times, how can I return one of the ID's from those 3 records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return either the `Max` or `Min` Bug Id

```
SELECT TOP(10) COUNT([BugTitle]) AS 'BugCount', [BugTitle], [ErrLine], MIN([BugId]) AS 'BugId'
FROM [Bugs] 
WHERE [BugDate] >= DateAdd(Day, -30, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate())) 
GROUP BY [BugTitle], [ErrLine]
ORDER BY COUNT([BugTitle]) DESC
```